# Gatsby plugin Graph QL error - saying the correct query is the same as the incorrect one

Tags: graph, graphql, gatsby

Having some issues with my Graph QL, hoping someone can give me a hand (yes I already Googled this extensively  and fixed part of the bug)

```
My app is saying the query is wrong and the expected is the same query that is wrong. I think it is how the query is structured.

const useBlogPosts = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allContentfulContentType(sort: { order: DESC, fields: ContentfulContentTypeFieldsEnum}) {
          edges {
            node {
              title
              author {
                name
              }
              ContentfulContentTypeFieldsEnum
              body {
                childMarkdownRemark {
                  html
                }
              }
              heroImage {
                fluid(maxWidth: 960) {
                  ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
  return data;
};
```

Comment: Hi! Please specify what the correct & incorrect queries are, what the expected behavior is, and what the current problem is. It'll be easier for us to help you!

Comment: ah missed the error message! The error said ContentfulContentTypeFieldsEnum is wrong and Graph QL expected ContentfulContentTypeFieldsEnum. I think the issue is in the actaul graph QL query above. It only makes sense to me since how can the right answer also be wrong.

Comment: I also already deleted and reinstalled sharp and gatsby sharp plugins since those are usually the culprit in my experience. and I am using a starter template to connect to Contentful (already connected w the API tokens just fine!)

Comment: @Boken I tried that but it did not work - I was thinking maybe I am missing brackets but no